# Question about turing machines

Tags: turing-machines

I've been reading a book about turing machines and it has a challenge about a building a Turing Machine that has as many 0s as many 1s but that can appear in any order.

I don't understand how do you set the reading to the beginning and then make a transition to the beginning.

But it deals with only 0s that shows up before 1s, how would i go about in the same instance if i find something like 100, or 100001?

Comment: What does it mean for a Turing Machine to "have" 0s and 1s ?

Comment: A TM can read any symbol and work like an algorithm, so i don't know

Comment: My guess is that what you want is a TM that decides the language $\{ w \in \{0,1\}^* \, : \, |w|_0 = 2 |w|_1 \}$, where $|w|_x$ denotes the number of occurrences of character $x \in \{0,1\}$ in $w$. But only you can know this for sure...

Comment: I would like to know exactly an algorithm for a TM that accepts strings where W0 = 2W1, as you said, but 0 and 1 can be read in any order

Comment: (Your edit made the title overly generic. And it invalidates not only [Steven's guess](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/127201/#comment266045_127201), but your affirmation of that, too - prio 1: get question title& body into shape 2:do something about the comment *if it still doesn't fit the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Turing machine uses the tape alphabet $\Gamma = \{0,1,x,\epsilon\}$.
Writing down all the transitions explicitly is tedious, so I'll just summarize the main steps:

- Move right until you find a 1 or $\epsilon$.
- If a 1 is found proceed as follows:

  - Replace the $1$ with $x$.
  - Move the head back to the initial position (move left until you find $\epsilon$, then move right once).
  - Move right until you find a $0$ or $\epsilon$. If no $0$ is found reject.
  - Replace the 0 with $x$.
  - Move right until you find a $0$ or $\epsilon$. If no $0$ is found reject.
  - Replace the 0 with $x$.
  - Move the head back to the initial position.
  - Repeat everything from the very first step.
- Otherwise, if no 1 is found:

  - Move left until you find a $0$ or $\epsilon$. If no 0 is found, accept.
  - Reject.

Comment: its a good solution, but it wont accept 010 for instance

Comment: Sure it does. Could you describe why you say it does not? These are the states of  the tape during the computation that accepts $010$:  $010 \to 0x0 \to xx0 \to xxx$.

Comment: i just figured, i don't know how to move left until i find ϵ. The head will always look right, yes? from my understanding if i have like >100. I can do: 1>00, 10>0, 100>, or this case, xxx. But what transitions should i do to go backwards and find ϵ, because if i do 100>, 10>0, 1>00, >100 i will find X. It'll be xxx>, xx>x, x>xx, >xxx. Could you give me a formal example of transitions that does it?

Comment: The head looks on the current tape cell. Neither left nor right. Say the head is somewhere in the tape and the current symbol is not $\epsilon$. You want to reset the head at the beginning of the input (e.g., to implement the 4th bullet in my answer). You start from some state $q_A$ and want to end up in state $q_B$ once the head has been reset. You will have these transitions: $(q_A, \alpha) \to (q_A, \alpha, \text{left}) \forall \alpha \in \{0,1,x\}$, $(q_A, \epsilon) \to (q_B, \epsilon, \text{right})$.

Comment: What i am trying: (QA, 1) -> (QB, X, R); 
 (QA, 0) -> (QA, 0, R);
 (QB, ϵ) -> (QB,  ϵ,  L);
 (QB,0) -> (QB,  0, R);
 (QB, 1) -> (QB, 1, R);
 (QB, X) -> (QB, X, R) When, i get to QC i have this 100>, im feeling stupid now lol

Comment: [Here](http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/jkyxfldisv) is an actual implementation. Try it, e.g., with input 001010

Comment: Sorry. I am not willing to spend more time on this by also drawing the diagrams. I just spent half an hour writing an implementation for you, even though I said in my answer that I was not going to do so. It should be easy for you to construct the diagrams from the transition function in the implementation.

Comment: Sorry, we posted at the same time, did not see your implementation, thank you.